# How to use 'reach' in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

How can I use reach when talking about fans trying to touch a band who's on stage?

"Reach" meaning to strech your arm to touch something.

1. They are reaching for the band.
2. They're reaching out for the band.
3. They're reaching (out) to touch the band.

Comment: #1 and #3 sound good.  #2 would sound more natural as "reaching out *toward* the band"

Comment: #3 sounds best.

Comment: Also "the fans are stretching to reach the band on stage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form 2 suggests to me some metaphorical use, not physically attempting to touch the band. The use of "out" in 3 would to some extent suggest the same thing to me. Form 1, or 3 without the word "out" seem reasonable natural to me.